# Changing refresh rate under full screen mode in directx11 code does not work

Tags: c++, directx-11

I want to be able to change refresh rate after first initialization in code.
I used DX11.0
From what I know so far, there are basically 2 ways to do this.
The first one is to recreate the swapchain with the desired refreshrate using IDXGIFactory::CreateSwapChain.
The second one is to use IDXGISwapChain::ResizeTarget. Fill the description with the desired refreshrate.

Below is my code for the first method:

```
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapchain_desc;
ZeroMemory(&swapchain_desc,sizeof(swapchain_desc));
sSwapChain->GetDesc(&swapchain_desc);//get the description from the original swapchain

//release the backbuffer
sContext->ClearState();
sContext->Flush();

sBackBufferRenderTargetView.Release();
sBackBufferTexture.Release();

//release the current swapchain
sSwapChain.Release();

//create the new swapchain with my desired refreshrate
swapchain_desc.BufferDesc.Width = sDeviceMode.dmPelsWidth;//sDeviceMode is a device mode specified by user
swapchain_desc.BufferDesc.Height = sDeviceMode.dmPelsHeight;
swapchain_desc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator= sDeviceMode.dmDisplayFrequency;
swapchain_desc.Windowed = false;

COMPtr<IDXGISwapChain> pSwapChain;
HRESULT hr = sDXGIFactory->CreateSwapChain(sD3D11Device,&swapchain_desc,&pSwapChain);
gAssert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
hr = pSwapChain->QueryInterface(&sSwapChain);
gAssert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

sSwapChain->SetFullscreenState(true,nullptr);
```

I should mention that the other settings get from original swapchain description are totally valid. 
When I pass resolution 1280*800 and refreshrate as 75HZ to the code, the return result of createswapchain is S_OK, meaning that swapchain is created successfully, but when I check the refreshrate showed on my monitor hardware, it's not changed, the hardware shows the resolution as 1920*1080 and refreshrate as 60HZ.

Then I tried the second method, here's the code block:

```
DXGI_MODE_DESC mode_desc;
ZeroMemory(&mode_desc,sizeof(mode_desc));

mode_desc.Width = sDeviceMode.dmPelsWidth;
mode_desc.Width = sDeviceMode.dmPelsHeight;
mode_desc.RefreshRate.Numerator= sDeviceMode.dmDisplayFrequency;
mode_desc.RefreshRate.Denominator= 1;
mode_desc.Format = swapchain_desc.BufferDesc.Format;
mode_desc.Scaling= swapchain_desc.BufferDesc.Scaling;

hr = sSwapchain->ResizeTarget(&mode_desc);
gAssert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

sSwapChain->SetFullscreenState(true,nullptr);
```

the returned result of  sSwapchain->ResizeTarget is also S_OK, but my desired refreshrate doesn't get set up to the monitor.

If there's anyone who can point out my mistakes it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says you must set `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH` flag in `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC::Flags` field to be able to switch video modes.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhh!!! That solved the problem! Thank you soooooooo much!!